# How to create backup image of Ubuntu with all Ros packages installed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used the DJdup backup tool but it only makes the image of linux not ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188120/how-to-create-backup-image-of-ubuntu-with-all-ros-packages-installed/) by [DCD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5339/dcd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might not be what you need exactly but it can also be considered as a backup that can directly be used on other computer. After setting up my development environment and after I compiled many packages by hand, I wanted to have a portable version of my Ubuntu that I can run directly on any other computer just by plugging my external hard drive and booting from it, continuing working on my packages as if nothing changed. For that I just used DD to clone my current Ubuntu Partition to a partition in my external hard drive.

> dd :
> http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/learning-linux-commands-dd

But one important thing: BE CAREFUL, read the tutorial again and again, if you switch the source hard drive and target hard drive, you will lose all your data.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DCD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5339/dcd/) on 2014-07-29**:
Thanks a lot

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-07-29**:
You might also be interested in clonezilla: http://clonezilla.org/. It seems to work faster than dd from my experience.

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2014-07-29**:
+1 for Clonezilla - I have used it at work to clone Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS desktop-full installed and it works great. Fast and straight-forward

**Comment by [DCD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5339/dcd/) on 2014-07-30**:
I have Ubuntu 12.04 precise installed through wubi installer. i only want to make linux system backup.
not the all disk drives.
How to do that?

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-07-30**:
I don't know how to do it when using Wubi, but is there any reason you are using Wubi? It is not recommended and having Ubuntu on its own partition makes things much easier.

**Comment by [DCD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5339/dcd/) on 2014-07-31**:
because i have two operating systems.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-07-31**:
I also have two operating systems. Look for tutorials on how to create a new partition from an already used partition (in your case windows partition I guess). Gparted is a good software for that, once your hard drive is divided you can choose from which OS to boot.